AlpineJs 3 and Charts.js (4.4.6) gives Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when calling Chart.update()
I'm tring to update my chart with new data. But whenever I call update functions I get error: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    <div x-data="chartComponent()" class="max-w-xl mx-auto">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        <button
            @click="updateChart"
            class="mt-4 px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
        >
            Update Chart
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function chartComponent() {
            return {
                chart: null,
                data: {
                    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Sales',
                        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                init() {
                    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: this.data,
                        options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            plugins: {
                                legend: {
                                    position: 'top',
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    callbacks: {
                                        label: function (context) {
                                            return `${context.label}: ${context.raw}`;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                updateChart() {
                    this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
                    this.chart.update();
                }
            };
        }
    </script>

I found that Alpine js works well Charts.js not higher then 2.9.4. Starting from v3 it gives such error.

Why do you need to have chart (the chart instance) as a property of the state object? Why not declare chart as a local variable in chartComponent function instead? See fiddle

The chart instance is known to not be working (well) with reactivity - there are multiple posts here on this with other frameworks, search for chart.js and reactivity; see this good one or even this with the funny (but probably working) solution of applying Object.seal. The chart instance is a hugely complex object, with circular references and even if you haven't had infinite recursion, it would've been a huge strain to your app to  have it observable.

I have found an temporary solution that wil simply first destroy the chart and then reinitialize it and somehow preventing the error.
    function chartComponent() {
        return {
            chart: null,
            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Sales',
                    data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            init() {
                const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: this.data,
                    options: {
                       responsive: true,
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            position: 'top',
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function (context) {
                                    return `${context.label}: ${context.raw}`;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            updateChart() {
                this.data.datasets[0].data = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
                this.chart.destroy();
                this.init();
            }
        };
    }
    

Prevent that people can stress test the update button on this solution because it then will break. It breaks if you try to update before the whole chart is loaded.
or
You will make chart a local variable so it wont cause crashes (this is provided by user @kikon)
function chartComponent() {
let chart = null;
return {
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sales',
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    init() {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: this.data,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (context) {
                                return `${context.label}: ${context.raw}`;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
    updateChart() {
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
        chart.update();
    }
};}

